# How to get rows from multiple tables when there is an ID association

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and my Database structure is as showed below,

```
Table: product
Structure: product_id - manufacturer_id
Example #1: 30 - 9
Example #2: 31 - 0
```

---

There is not manufacturer_id 0 in the table.

```
Table: manufacturer
Structure: manufacturer_id - name
Example #1: 9 - Canon
```

---

So, I tried to use this code below but the product ID 9 is not listed

```
SELECT product.product_id, IF(product.manufacturer_id > 0, manufacturer.name, 'Unknown') AS manufacturer FROM product, manufacturer WHERE product.manufacturer_id=manufacturer.manufacturer_id ORDER BY product.product_id ASC
```

---

```
Structure: product_id - manufacturer
Output:
    30 - Canon
```

---

I need to get an output like this one:

```
Structure: product_id - manufacturer
Output:
    30 - Canon
    31 - Unknown
```

---

I have searched a lot and tried do it in many different ways but no success.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product.id, ISNULL(manufacturer.name, 'Unknown name') FROM Product INNER JOIN manufacturer ON(Product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT op.product_id, IFNULL(om.name, 'Unknown')
FROM oc_product op
LEFT JOIN oc_manufacturer om ON op.product_id = om.manufacturer_id
ORDER BY op.product_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

After test both answers, I found this one working:

```
SELECT product.product_id, IFNULL(manufacturer.name, 'Unknown') FROM product LEFT JOIN manufacturer ON product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id ORDER BY product.product_id ASC
```

Thank you for your help guys.